# Traceback (most recent call last): BlenderGIS

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, vector-mapping, meta-objects

I'm using the BlenderGIS add on. When importing digital terrain models (or DEMS) which are ESRI ASCII Grid (.asc) files, I get this error message.
I'm pretty new to blender but trying to create 3D maps as it seems to be better than QGIS currently so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you screenshot the entire traceback and add it to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can find the entire traceback printout by going Window > Toggle System Console. Please copy / paste it in its entirety :)

Comment: Also make sure your problem isnt answered in https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/305 or https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/265 or https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues

Comment: @MartyFouts Image now in description. Hopefully this helps

Comment: @Community I've made the post a bit more specific now.